# When the upper sum $U[f;P]$ equals the lower sum $L[f;P]$ for a measurable partition $P$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I know if there exists a measurable partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$ when
$$
\inf_P U[f;P] = \sup_P L[f;P]$$
where the infemum and supremum are over all measurable partitions.

However, what can I say the function f if  $U[f;P]$=$L[f;P]$?

Comment: Are $U[f;P]$ and $L[f;P]$ the infemum and supremum over all measurable partitions $P$?  If so, this is poor notation.

Comment: Aha!  @glacier has messed up the notation.  I will fix it.

Comment: @OP Any idea of your own? Frankly, I am surprised that none comes to anybody who knows what upper/lower Riemann sums are... You might want to draw a figure.

Comment: @OP It will help to prove a small lemma first: Suppose $E$ is equipped with the Lebesgue measure, and let $f$ be a bounded function on some compact set $O\subset E$. Show that if $\inf_{x\in O} f(x)=\sup_{x\in O} f(x)$ then $f$ is constant on $O$.